# Prestashop beforeRequest Middleware

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to build a module for Prestashop 1.6 that would redirect the user if the targeted URL is present in a database.

What I'm going to do is the following:

```
public function checkRedirection ($url) {
    $line = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM ps_custom_redirection WHERE url = ' . pSQL($url));

    if (!sizeof($line)) {
        return null;
    }

    header('Location: ' . $line[0]['destination']);
    http_response_code($line[0]['http_code']);
    exit();
}
```

Now, I could run this function when the `displayTop` hook is fired. But I would rather launch this function at the beginning of the request's process.

**Does Prestashop provide such a hook? If not, can I create one? Where should I write the code to fire it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fist hook executed is `actionDispatcher` – you can use it if you want.

You'll find this hook executed in `/classes/Dispatcher.php`. Search for the code `Hook::exec('actionDispatcher', $params_hook_action_dispatcher);`.

If you want to add this hook to your module, you need to use its name in the main module file like this:

`public function install() {
    return parent::install()
    && $this->registerHook('actionDispatcher');
}`

`public function hookActionDispatcher($params) {
    // your code
    Tools::redirect($url);
}`

In Prestashop `Tools::redirect($url);` is used if redirecting.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is it normal that I can't find the `actionDispatcher` in my `ps_hook` table?

Comment: Yes, it is. If you have nothing added to this hook, there is no record added to the database table `ps_hook`.

Comment: @Hammerbot Don't rely on database entries for hooks but rather search for `Hook::exec` and `{hook h=` in prestashop files to find all available hooks.